# Toggle closest DIV in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with checkboxes that have a class of .toggle-extract and when clicked I'd like them to toggle the closest DIV with the class name .extract-years

Now the code I have should work, but it is driving me nuts trying to figure out why it won't trigger.

here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vo0uzzuh/) example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-extract').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('div').find('.extract-years').toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

and here is the HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-extract">
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="extract-years">Toggle Box</div>
        </td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-extract">
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="extract-years">Toggle Box</div>
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `closest` will select the parent `div` of the input

Comment: and to complement @SamBattat 's comment,  the class `.toggle-extract` does not have a parent `div` (at least in the HTML code provided)

Comment: that seems to work, however one thing I did leave out is that the checkboxes are inside a <table> like so: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywbh2m3q/1/)

Comment: Adjusted it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vswem9ub/ , should I add this to the answer to the first version?

Comment: @matthias-h yes please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change to

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.extract-years').toggle("fast");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-extract').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.extract-years').toggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #000;
}
.extract-years {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-extract">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="extract-years">Toggle Box</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-extract">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="extract-years">Toggle Box</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywbh2m3q/)

**Update:** for the second version mentioned as comment, the select statement can be changed to e.g.

```
$(this).closest('table').parent("td").next("td").
        find('.extract-years').toggle("fast");
```

Adjusted [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vswem9ub/), and working version here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-extract').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('table').parent("td").next("td").find('.extract-years').toggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #000;
}
.extract-years {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="inline-table-body">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-extract">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="extract-years">Toggle Box</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="inline-table-body">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-extract">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="extract-years">Toggle Box</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: See my updated code, where this example doesn't work. [Updated Code](http://jsfiddle.net/ywbh2m3q/1/)